# JQUERY dynamically created table. Trying to hide entire column

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is creating my table and working -  It creates a table and I am going to have it check a list to hide columns. For testing purposes I am trying to hide the colun "Proj_Type" it does hide the header but does not hide the actual column of data. I want the entire thing to hide.

```
  function createTab(Name, id) {
        var $button = $('<button/>', {
            'class': 'tablinks',
            'onclick': 'return false;',
            'id': name,
            text: Name,
            click: function () {
                return false;
            }
        });
        var $div = $('<div>').prop({
            id: Name,
            'name': id + 'MKTTAB',
            className: 'tabcontent'
        })
        var $table = $('<table/>', {
            'class': 'GRD1',
            id: id + "GRDMKTLIST",
        }
        )
        $table.append('<caption>' + Name + '</caption>')
        var $tbody = $table.append('<tbody />').children('tbody');
        $tbody.append('<tr />').children('tr:last');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../WebMethods/MarketPersuitMethods.aspx/GetQueryInfo",
            data: {},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function (d) {
                var data = $.parseJSON(d.d);
                var colHeader = Object.keys(data[0]);
                for (var i = 0; i < colHeader.length; i++) {
                    if (colHeader[i] != "notes") {
                        $tbody.append("<th>" + colHeader[i] + "</th>");
                    }
                }
                //sets new line
                $tbody.append('<tr />').children('tr:last')
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                    for (var j = 0; j < colHeader.length; j++) {
                        if (colHeader[j] != "notes") {
                            $tbody.append('<td>' + data[i][colHeader[j]] + '</td>');
                        }
                    }
                    $tbody.append('<tr />').children('tr:last')
                }

                setTimeout(function () {
                }, 1000);
            }

        });
        $($table.find('th')).each(function () {
            var indextest = $(this).index() + 1;
            
if ($(this).text() == "Proj_Type") {
                $('[id*=GRDMKTLIST] td:nth-child(' + indextest + '),th:nth-child(' + indextest + ')').hide();
            }

        })
        $button.appendTo('#tabs');
        $table.appendTo($div);
        $div.appendTo('#TabbedMktList');
   
       
    }
```

However, on the bottom where i have

```
if ($(this).text() == "Proj_Type") {
                $('[id*=GRDMKTLIST] td:nth-child(' + indextest + '),th:nth-child(' + indextest + ')').hide();
            }
```

This only hides the header and I am trying to hide the entire column TD included.

Comment: Your selector *should* be:  `$("#id td:nth-child(0),#id th:nth-child(0)")` (where 0 = your indextest).   As it's working for `th` and not for `td` and you're missing the `#id` prefix on the `th` side, it looks like your selector `'[id*=GRDMKTLIST]'` is incorrect and not finding anything.

Comment: Your issue is that `$(..)` will look in the DOM - but your `$table` hasn't been added to the DOM yet, so finds nothing.  You could move your `$table.find(th).each` to after all the append lines.   Or you could change `$('[id*=GRDMKTLIST] ...` to `$table.find('td:nth-child(' + indextest + '),th:nth-child(' + indextest + ')').hide()`

Comment: I have tried the following
 $($table.find('th')).each(function () {
            var indextest = $(this).index() + 1;
            if ($(this).text() == "Proj_Type") {
                //$('[id*=GRDMKTLIST] td:nth-child(' + indextest + '),th:nth-child(' + indextest + ')').hide();
                $table.find('td:nth-child(' + indextest + '),th:nth-child(' + indextest + ')').hide()
            }
        })
It does not seem to make a difference. The information below the header is still displayed. The header gets hidden but not the TD for each row below it in that column index.

Comment: Why not just not add it in the first place?  Same as you already do with `"notes"` column:  `if (colHeader[i] != "notes") {` -> `if (colHeader[i] != "notes" && colHeader[i] != "Project_Type") {`

Comment: I only added the thing about the "notes" field becuase it was huge and hurt my eyes. I am having this set so that there are checkboxes to hide/show columns on the table. However, something that should be so simple is now driving me insane.  I need it hidden and not completely left out of creation.

Comment: As another thing to add to the confusion - 

I created a button and had it execute the function to remove at specific index for testing. 
After page fully loaded. It also only removes the header and not the TD below it. 

 function CheckGrids() {
        $("[id*=GRDMKTLIST] th").each(function () {
            $(this).index(2).hide();
            $("[id*=GRDMKTLIST]  td:nth-child(" + 2 + "),th:nth-child(" + 2 + ")").hide();
        })
        return false;
    }

Comment: *hidden and not completely left out of creation* ah yes, an important distinction.  Just trying to find alternatives if your approach is not working for you.  Another alternative is to add `style='display:none` as you build the HTML, either in it's own `if` or something like `$tbody.append('<td ' + (colHeader[j] == 'Proj_Type' ? 'style="display:none;"' : "") + '>'`

Comment: Regarding your button click not working - see my first comment.  When you use `,` you need the *full* selector, as in `$("#id .class,#id class2")` but you have `$("#id .class,.class2")`

Comment: Even while changing my button to `$("[id*=GRDMKTLIST] th").each(function () {
            $("[id*=GRDMKTLIST]  td:nth-child(" + 2 + "),[id*=GRDMKTLIST] th:nth-child(" + 2 + ")").hide();
        })`

it still made no difference. I am so confused because assigning it to a button would ensure that the DOM is created. I literally see it all on my screen. It is only getting rid of the header and not the below. In the end it has to be something stupid it always is.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the rendered output  (maybe in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)) - at least let's see why it's not working for your post-build/-render button.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0k5h9em7/

Comment: Ok, your issue is that you're not adding your `td`/`th` to the `tr` you're doing `$tbody.append('<td` - so all the th/td are a child of body - look at the rendered output in the fiddle.  Updated fiddle with cells in rows and a button: https://jsfiddle.net/n168ra2g/   and then with it in the build (which you'd already included changes from comments above) https://jsfiddle.net/n168ra2g/3/ (missed tr in the data loop - add it at the start of the row, not before the loop and again at the end otherwise you get an extra tr you don't want)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main issues:

- `$('[id*=GRDMKTLIST]`

will look in the DOM, but your `$table` has not yet been added to the DOM, so does nothing.  Use `$table.find(...` to use the `$table` variable in memory.

- `$tbody.append('<td`

will append the `td` (and equivalent code for `th`) to the `tbody` - but these should be in a `tr`.
The browser will do some "magic" and see an empty `<tr></tr>` and put a new row in for you, but selectors for `tbody > tr > td` won't work.  This also means there's only a single `:nth-child(n)` per n, not per row (as all cells across all rows are siblings).

You can add a new row to `$tbody` and return the new row by using `.appendTo`

```
$tr = $("<tr>").appendTo($tbody);
```

then add the `th`/`td` to $tr and not $tbody

```
$tr.append('<td...`
```

---

Regarding the selector for `$table.find("td,th")` you don't need the `th` part as you're looping `th` and it's already `this`, so you can do:

```
$(this).hide();
$table.find('td:nth-child(' + indextest + ')').hide();
```

---

Also make sure you only create `tr` as you need it.  Your code create a `tr` before the data row loop and inside the data row loop, leaving an empty `tr`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  $tr = $("<tr>").appendTo($tbody);
  for (var j = 0; j < colHeader.length; j++) {
    if (colHeader[j] != "notes") {
      $tr.append('<td id=' + colHeader[j] + '>' + data[i][colHeader[j]] + '</td>');
    }
  }
}
```

Also updated in the fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/n168ra2g/3/